# Mount windows shared drive to MWAA in bootscript

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, airflow-2.x, cifs, mwaa

In MWAA startup script, I'm to mount a drive.
`sudo yum install samba-client cifs-utils -y`
`sudo mount.cifs //dev/test/drop /mnt/dev/test -o username=testuser,password='pwd',domain=XX`

Executing above commonds giving error - **Unable to apply new capability set.**

Also initially when I ran this command: `sudo mount -t cifs //dev/test/drop /mnt/dev/test-o username=testuser,password='pwd',domain=XX`
And tried to load cifs manually: sudo modprobe cifs
It was not able to load. I think kernel is not supported